# Centering a view on the screen when using a UIScrollView with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

If the title isn't clear enough, here's my situation.

I have a view controller set up like this:
self.view > scrollView > contentView(UIView) > multiple views stacked vertically, some containing images, others containing collection views of various heights, etc.

As you can see, this can make for a very tall scrollView, with a height that is not static.

What I want to do is display a UIActivityIndicatorView in the middle of the user's screen, no matter where they are in the scrollView. I keep ending up with the activityIndicator either in the center of the scrollView (which is NOT the same as the center of the phone screen), or it ends up in what would be the center of the screen if the user was scrolled all the way to the top, of course i can't assume that's where the user will be when i need to display the indicator.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` on `self.view`? (The view maintained by the `UIViewController` in which you want to show the activity indicator)

Comment: @Rikh this is the correct answer, can't believe I over looked this... If you would write this as an answer instead of a comment i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sure! Just did. It happens, sometimes its the simple things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the `UIActivityIndicator` on `self.view`. (The view maintained by the UIViewController in which you want to show the activity indicator)

Answer (score 0):

Better take activityindicator as self.view centre like this:

```
   var ac = UIActivityIndicator()
ac.frame = self.view.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using the main screen frame ;

```
activityIndicator.frame = (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)/2 , ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)/2 , 30, 30);
```